# Xcode can't open a file

Tags: xcode, file

I am hitting a problem I don't think I've ever seen before, in Xcode Version 14.0.1.

When I want to look at a certain file, I get this message:

```
*The file “CoreDataBox.swift” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.*

                **OK**
```

I can see in the terminal that the file couldn't have more permissions:

```
me@My-Mac Swift_ToolBox % ls -l CoreDataBox.swift 
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 me  staff  38727 Mar  4  2020 CoreDataBox.swift
me@My-Mac Swift_ToolBox %
```

I have other files showing up much less permissions in the terminal and at the same time opening up with no issue in Xcode

Can someone tell me what is missing here?

If I select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info as suggested in the Xcode message; it has absolutely no effect (even when changing the permissions).

Comment: The file in xCode is a symbolic link (@) to another file (the one you want to open) which may have other permissions.

Comment: Alright, and how do I solve the problem ? Or why does XCode consider that I do not have the proper permissions for a particular file ?

Comment: @matt. Yes, I understand sandboxing in general. But I am not sure to see exactly why it is actually needed here.

Comment: @matt. I started to read about the App Sandbox capability in Xcode. But since my app is an iOS one I am not quite sure if I can set App Sandbox.

Comment: @matt. I do not use the App Sandbox capability currently because I do not see any setting related to Sandbox in my Xcode. I guess this is because I never set this capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still do not understand why this problem happened.
(An explanation is welcome)

I solved it by removing the reference to the file in Xcode and then adding the file again.

The issue disappeared after that.

Comment: It sounds like you added the file wrong originally.